# C# Word Interop formatting paragraph line spacing only affects last line

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I have the below code which creates a paragraph with some formatting and adds it to the end of my document. The font formatting for bold, name, italic and size is applied to the entire paragraph, however the lineunitafter, lineunitbefore, and linespacingrule only apply for the last line of my paragraph, not the lines before.

It makes no sense to me, am I missing something?

```
Word.Paragraph oParaMacroName;
oParaMacroName = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
oParaMacroName.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
oParaMacroName.Range.Font.Name = "Courier New";
oParaMacroName.Range.Font.Italic = 1;
oParaMacroName.Range.Font.Size = 10;
oParaMacroName.Range.Text = macro.Definition;
oParaMacroName.Range.ParagraphFormat.LineUnitAfter = 0.1F;
oParaMacroName.Range.ParagraphFormat.LineUnitBefore = 0.1F;
oParaMacroName.Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle;
oParaMacroName.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Comment: i would suggest abandoning the interop and going straight to the Open XML SDK, https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK it allows you to directly edit the document without having to load up word

Comment: Hi Mike, that looks like a very nice library, but for the time being I need to solve the current issue I have in interop.

Comment: the interop if a legacy system from the old office 2000 suite, the only reason its still included is for back-compatibility, that library is the opensource  fork of the Microsoft Developed Open XML SDK. you are trying to use a technology thats 15 years out of date

Comment: I'll look into it for future projects, but with this one I can't switch.

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference, but... `LineUnitAfter` and `LineUnitBefore` aren't typical properties for non-Asian text. In a non-Asian UI the setting appears in `SpaceAfter` and `SpaceBefore`, which is what you should use if the font doesn't lay out in a grid. Note the information in the language reference: "Returns or sets the amount of spacing **(in gridlines)** after the specified paragraph." And note that this setting will apply to individual lines, depending on how Word interprets them, and not to the entire paragraph. What is it, exactly, that you want to accomplish with these commands?

Comment: I want to set the line spacing to single and the spacing before and spacing after to 0pt for the entire paragraph. I believe because it is only setting the last line of my paragraph correctly, it somehow sees each line as a separate paragraph maybe. Could it be the newline escape which is creating separate paragraphs maybe?